# console.error throws exception

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have a JavaScript file (Angular, but I don;t think that's anything to do with it).

`console.log` works fine, but `console.error` throws `* TypeError: Cannot find function error in object [object Object].`

```
console.log('An error occurred while searching. Status code was ' + status);
console.error('An error occurred while searching. Status code was ' + status);
```

I'm running test using Jasmine, maybe Jasmine mocks\injects it's own console??

**UPDATE**
This is being run via a mvn build with Jasmine, so no browser.

Comment: can you type console.log and console.browser into the `console` directly and see if they return their function code - this is easy to do in Safari.

Comment: Your mvn built with Jasmine obviously does'nt have a `console.error` function, so it's probably not supported.

Comment: I have just found the problem, it's as @adeneo thought.  The noop implementation of console we are using doesn't have a stubbed error function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that the no-op implementation of console we default to didn't have a stubbed error method.

e.g:

```
/**
 * Defines a console object if missing
 */
if (typeof console !== "object") {
    console = {};
    console.log = function() {};
    console.error=function() {};  // Added this to fix
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var console = (function () {
    function log(msg) {
    }
    function error(msg) {
    }
    function info(msg) {
    }
    return {
        log: log,
        error: error,
        info: info
    };
})();
```

Include this content in "Mocks.js"(or give any file_name) in your project's pom.xml